# Slice index greater than length and less than capacity gives error

Tags: go

Following code gives a error at runtime.

```
package main

import fmt "fmt"

func main(){

    type b []int
    var k = make([]b, 5, 10)
    fmt.Printf("%d\n",k[8])
    fmt.Printf("%d", len(k))
}
```

Error is as follows.

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

runtime.panic+0x9e /go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1060
        runtime.panic(0x453b00, 0x300203f0)
runtime.panicstring+0x94 /go/src/pkg/runtime/runtime.c:116
        runtime.panicstring(0x4af6c6, 0xc)
runtime.panicindex+0x26 /go/src/pkg/runtime/runtime.c:73
        runtime.panicindex()
main.main+0x8d C:/GOEXCE~1/basics/DATATY~1/slice.go:9
        main.main()
runtime.mainstart+0xf 386/asm.s:93
        runtime.mainstart()
runtime.goexit /go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:178
        runtime.goexit()
----- goroutine created by -----
_rt0_386+0xbf 386/asm.s:80
```

While if `k[0]` or `k[1]` is printed, it runs fine. Can you please explain what exactly capacity means for slices.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply indexing, so the index must be less than the length. The [relevant section of the Go specification](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Indexes) says that

> A primary expression of the form
>
> a[x]
>
> ...
>
> For a of type A or *A where A is an array type, or for a of type S
>   where S is a slice type:
>
> x must be an integer value and 0 <= x < len(a)

However, if you were "slicing" (e.g. `a[6:9]`), then it would work with indexes that are greater than the length but within the capacity.

Answer (score 0):

```
var slice = make([]b, 5, 10)
```

is equal to

```
var array [10]b
slice := array[:5]
```

The difference is that when you use `var slice = make([]b, 5, 10)`, you can't access the `array` under `slice`. The `slice := array[:5]` means the first element of `slice` is `array[0]` and the length of `slice` is 5, which means `slice[0] == array[0], slice[1] == array[1], ... slice[4] == array[4]`. Because you can only access the index that is less than the length(which means `0 <= index < length`). The length of `slice` is 5 and the length of `array` is 10, so you can access `array[8]`(0<=8<10) but can't access `slice[8]`(8>5).

Full sample:

```
package main

import fmt "fmt"

func main(){

    type b []int
    var array [10]b
    slice := array[:5]
    // []
    fmt.Printf("%d\n",slice[1])
    // []
    fmt.Printf("%d\n",array[8])
    // panic: runtime error: index out of range
    fmt.Printf("%d\n",slice[8])
}
```

### Reference

1. https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals